# Error while inserting into db using doctrine ORM

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I am trying to insert data into db ,but it shows some error like this[image: Image of the error]

My model Entity

> Request.php

```
 is here `<?php


namespace EvolisClientRequest\Model\Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Request
{
    /**
     * @var \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Salesperson", inversedBy="request")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="request_salesperson")
     * @var Salesperson
     */
    private $salesperson;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="request")
     * @var Client
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Status", inversedBy="request")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="request_status")
     * @var Status
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var Qualification
     */
    private $qualification;

    /**
     * @return \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Salesperson
     */
    public function getSalesperson()
    {
        return $this->salesperson;
    }

    /**
     * @param Salesperson $salesperson
     */
    public function setSalesperson($salesperson)
    {
        $this->salesperson = $salesperson;
    }

    /**
     * @return Client
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    /**
     * @param Client $client
     */
    public function setClient($client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * @return Status
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * @param Status $status
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    /**
     * @return Qualification
     */
    public function getQualification()
    {
        return $this->qualification;
    }

    /**
     * @param Qualification $qualification
     */
    public function setQualification($qualification)
    {
        $this->qualification = $qualification;
    }

    public function __construct($salesperson, $client, $status, $qualification) {
        $this->salesperson = $salesperson;
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->qualification = $qualification;
    }
```

}`

Also my

> DAO "RequestBaseDao.php" is here,which is automatically generated.

```
    <?php

/*
* This file has been automatically generated by Mouf/ORM.
* DO NOT edit this file, as it might be overwritten.
* If you need to perform changes, edit the RequestDao class instead!
*/

namespace EvolisClientRequest\Model\DAOs;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException;
use Mouf\Doctrine\ORM\Event\SaveListenerInterface;
use EvolisClientRequest\Model\Entities\Request;

/**
 * The RequestBaseDao class will maintain the persistence of Request class into the request table.
 *
 * @method Request findByQualification($fieldValue, $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 * @method Request findOneByQualification($fieldValue, $orderBy = null)
 * @method Request findBySurfaceMin($fieldValue, $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 * @method Request findOneBySurfaceMin($fieldValue, $orderBy = null)
 * @method Request findBySurfaceMax($fieldValue, $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 * @method Request findOneBySurfaceMax($fieldValue, $orderBy = null)
 * @method Request findByPriceMin($fieldValue, $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 * @method Request findOneByPriceMin($fieldValue, $orderBy = null)
 * @method Request findByPriceMax($fieldValue, $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 * @method Request findOneByPriceMax($fieldValue, $orderBy = null)
 * @method Request findByRequestDate($fieldValue, $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 * @method Request findOneByRequestDate($fieldValue, $orderBy = null)

 */
class RequestBaseDao extends EntityRepository
{

    /**
     * @var SaveListenerInterface[]
     */
    private $saveListenerCollection;

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @param SaveListenerInterface[] $saveListenerCollection
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, array $saveListenerCollection = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($entityManager, $entityManager->getClassMetadata('EvolisClientRequest\Model\Entities\Request'));
        $this->saveListenerCollection = $saveListenerCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Get a new persistent entity
     * @param ...$params
     * @return Request
     */
    public function create(...$params) : Request
    {
        $entity = new Request(...$params);
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);
        return $entity;
    }

    /**
     * Peforms a flush on the entity.
     *
     * @param Request
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function save(Request $entity)
    {
        foreach ($this->saveListenerCollection as $saveListener) {
            $saveListener->preSave($entity);
        }

        $this->getEntityManager()->flush($entity);

        foreach ($this->saveListenerCollection as $saveListener) {
            $saveListener->postSave($entity);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Peforms remove on the entity.
     *
     * @param Request $entity
     */
    public function remove(Request $entity)
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);
    }

    /**
     * Finds only one entity. The criteria must contain all the elements needed to find a unique entity.
     * Throw an exception if more than one entity was found.
     *
     * @param array $criteria
     *
     * @return Request
     */
    public function findUniqueBy(array $criteria) : Request
    {
        $result = $this->findBy($criteria);

        if (count($result) === 1) {
            return $result[0];
        } elseif (count($result) > 1) {
            throw new NonUniqueResultException('More than one Request was found');
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds only one entity by Qualification.
     * Throw an exception if more than one entity was found.
     *
     * @param mixed $fieldValue the value of the filtered field
     *
     * @return Request
     */
    public function findUniqueByQualification($fieldValue)
    {
        return $this->findUniqueBy(array('qualification' => $fieldValue));
    }
}
```

My RequestDao.php where i can write queries.

```
    <?php
namespace EvolisClientRequest\Model\DAOs;
use EvolisClientRequest\Model\Entities\Request;


/**
* The RequestDao class will maintain the persistence of Request class into the request table.
*/
class RequestDao extends RequestBaseDao {

    /*** PUT YOUR SPECIFIC QUERIES HERE !! ***/

    public function setdata()
    {
        /*$product = new Request();
        $product->setStatus('Keyboard');
        $product->setClient('000000001ae10dda000000003c4667a6');
        $product->setSalesperson('Ergonomic and stylish!');
        $product->setQualification('1111');
        //var_dump($r);die();
        $em = $this->getEntityManager(); 
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();*/
       $product= $this->create('Keyboard','000000001ae10dda000000003c4667a6','Ergonomic and stylish!','1111');
        $this->save($product);

    }
}
```

Finally my Controller "ContactController.php"

```
   <?php
namespace EvolisClientRequest\Controllers;

use EvolisClientRequest\Model\DAOs\ClientDao;
use EvolisClientRequest\Model\Entities\Client;
use EvolisClientRequest\Model\Entities\Clients;
use EvolisClientRequest\Model\DAOs\RequestDao;
use EvolisClientRequest\Model\Entities\Request;
use EvolisClientRequest\Model\Entities\Requests;
use EvolisClientRequest\Model\DAOs\SalespersonDao;
use EvolisClientRequest\Model\Entities\Salesperson;
use EvolisClientRequest\Model\Entities\Salespersons;
use Mouf\Mvc\Splash\Annotations\Get;
use Mouf\Mvc\Splash\Annotations\Post;
use Mouf\Mvc\Splash\Annotations\Put;
use Mouf\Mvc\Splash\Annotations\Delete;
use Mouf\Mvc\Splash\Annotations\URL;
use Mouf\Html\Template\TemplateInterface;
use Mouf\Html\HtmlElement\HtmlBlock;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use \Twig_Environment;
use Mouf\Html\Renderer\Twig\TwigTemplate;
use Mouf\Mvc\Splash\HtmlResponse;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;
use Zend\Diactoros\Response\JsonResponse;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * TODO: write controller comment
 */
class ContactController {

    /**
     * The logger used by this controller.
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * The template used by this controller.
     * @var TemplateInterface
     */
    private $template;

    /**
     * The header of the page.
     * @var HtmlBlock
     */
    private $header;


    /**
     * The main content block of the page.
     * @var HtmlBlock
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * The Twig environment (used to render Twig templates).
     * @var Twig_Environment
     */
    private $twig;


    /**
     * Controller's constructor.
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger The logger
     * @param TemplateInterface $template The template used by this controller
     * @param HtmlBlock $content The main content block of the page
     * @param Twig_Environment $twig The Twig environment (used to render Twig templates)
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, TemplateInterface $template, HtmlBlock $content, HtmlBlock $header, Twig_Environment $twig, ClientDao $clientDao, RequestDao $requestDao, SalespersonDao $salespersonDao) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->template = $template;
        $this->content = $content;
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->header = $header;
        $this->clientDao = $clientDao;
        $this->requestDao = $requestDao;
        $this->salespersonDao = $salespersonDao;
    }

    /**
     * @URL("new.html")

     */
    public function new() {
        // TODO: write content of action here

        // Let's add the twig file to the template.
        $this->content->addHtmlElement(new TwigTemplate($this->twig, 'views/contact/new.twig', array("message"=>"world")));
        $this->header->addHtmlElement(new TwigTemplate($this->twig, 'views/root/header.twig', array("message"=>"world")));
        return new HtmlResponse($this->template);
    }

    /**
     * @URL("saveData")
     * For Saving the data
     */
    public function saveData()
    {
        /*$newClient = $this->clientDao->create('hello', 'sarathchandran@122.com','8907263949');
        $this->clientDao->save($newClient);*/
        //$data = array();
        //$data['salespersonDao']['salesperson'] = 'example@sales.com';
        //$data['request']['qualification'] = 'abcdefgh';

        //$newClient = $this->requestDao->create($data);
        //$newClient = $this->requestDao->setQualification('Keyboard');
       // $this->requestDao->save($newClient);
        $user_data=$this->requestDao->setdata();

        //return new JsonResponse([ "status"=>0 ]);
    }
}
```

I am using Mouf framework.I am stuck with this problem.Someone Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In `Request` class `salesperson` and `status` should be array collections, but you are assigning them as strings. Try using this example:
`$this->salesperson[] = $salesperson;` and etc with `status`

Comment: I did not get that.. can you make it clear

Comment: `ManyToMany` and `OneToMany` relations are always array collections, so variables should be arrays (ex.: http://pastebin.com/EsJNGMrk)

Comment: So should I change this in my entity?I am new one in this ORM I am getting confused

Comment: Yes, yours `salesperson` and `status` setters should set array. Also, dont forget to change it in constructor.
Ex.: `$this->salesperson[] = $salesperson;`

Comment: First read doctrine associations doc.: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html and the ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised by @rokas, you should really start reading more about Doctrine. This is not a Mouf issue, this is clearly a Doctrine ORM issue so the appropriate doc is here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/index.html

Here are a few tips:

Your controller calls the `setdata` method

```
$user_data=$this->requestDao->setdata();
```

The `setdata` method calls:

```
$product= $this->create('Keyboard','000000001ae10dda000000003c4667a6','Ergonomic and stylish!','1111');
```

Now, the `create` method is:

```
public function create(...$params) : Request
{
    $entity = new Request(...$params);
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);
    return $entity;
}
```

This means that it will call the `Request` constructor with this parameters:

```
$entity = new Request('Keyboard','000000001ae10dda000000003c4667a6','Ergonomic and stylish!','1111');
```

Have a look at the `Request` constructor:

```
public function __construct($salesperson, $client, $status, $qualification) {
    $this->salesperson = $salesperson;
    $this->client = $client;
    $this->status = $status;
    $this->qualification = $qualification;
}
```

As you can see, the first parameter is `$salesperson`. You try to put the value "Keyboard" here. The `$salesperson` attribute is defined this way:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Salesperson", inversedBy="request")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="request_salesperson")
 * @var Salesperson
 */
private $salesperson;

/**
 * @param Salesperson $salesperson
 */
public function setSalesperson($salesperson)
{
    $this->salesperson = $salesperson;
}
```

Now, here is your problem I think.

The `$salesperson` property is defined as a "ManyToMany" association. So you really cannot put a string in here, it is a collection of Salesperson. By the way, you should not "set" anything either. The setter should be completely removed.

Instead, you should consider using it as per the documentation here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

For instance:

```
$request->getSalesPersons()->add($someObjectRepresentingAPerson);
```

Also, notice that since the `$salesperson` represents a **collection** of Salesperson object, your should really name it `$salesPersons` (plural form)